# c#- Make a ball move left,right, up and down based on button click

Tags: c#, visual-studio, graphics

I'm trying to learn C# by developing a small little breakout game. It is coming along fine but I am struggling with moving the ball up, down, left and right based on the user clicks. I don't even know where to start for it as my code is that messy. Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Graphics drawingArea, paperBall, paperBat;
    Pen penBall;
    SolidBrush brushBAt = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    private int x, y, xChange, yChange;
    Random ranNum;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        drawingArea = playground.CreateGraphics();
        paperBall = playground.CreateGraphics();
        paperBat = playground.CreateGraphics();
        lblLives.Text = "5";
        lblScore.Text = "0";
        ranNum = new Random();
        drawBricks();
    }

    private void btnYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        drawBricks();
        drawBat();
        drawBall();

    }


    public void drawBricks()
    {
        SolidBrush blackpen = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        SolidBrush redpen = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        SolidBrush yellowpen = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);
        SolidBrush bluepen = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
        SolidBrush greenpen = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
        drawingArea.FillRectangle(blackpen, 0, 0, 80, 25);
        drawingArea.FillRectangle(redpen, 150, 0, 80, 25);
        drawingArea.FillRectangle(yellowpen, 350, 0, 80, 25);
        drawingArea.FillRectangle(bluepen, 550, 0, 80, 25);
        drawingArea.FillRectangle(greenpen, 750, 0, 80, 25);
    }

    public void drawBat()
    {
        paperBat = playground.CreateGraphics();
        playground.MouseMove += new
            System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(picDraw_MouseHover);
        //drawBall();

    }

    private void picDraw_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //paperBat.Clear(Color.White);


    }

     private void picDraw_MouseHover(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        paperBat.FillRectangle(brushBAt, e.X + -30, playground.Height - 15, 75, 10); //First one: high up it is Second one: how long it is Third one: 
        drawBricks();
    }


    public void drawBall()
    {
        penBall = new Pen(Color.Red);
        penBall.Width = 10;

        timer1.Interval = 50;
        timer1.Enabled = true;

        x = ranNum.Next(-10, playground.Height); //MAkes the ball spawn randomly
        y = ranNum.Next(-10, playground.Width);  //MAkes the ball spawn randomly


        xChange = ranNum.Next(1, 20); yChange = ranNum.Next(1, 20); //Changes speed
        //drawBricks();
        //drawBat();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x = x + xChange;
        y = y + yChange;
        if (x >= playground.Width)
            xChange = -xChange;

        if (y >= playground.Height)
            yChange = -yChange;

        if (x <= 0)
            xChange = -xChange;

        if (y <= 0)
            yChange = -yChange;

       // paperBall.Clear(Color.White);
        paperBat.Clear(Color.White);
        paperBall.DrawEllipse(penBall, x, y, 10, 10); //Height and width of ball
        drawBricks();


    }

    private void btnUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

}

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You are using the wrong tool for the job. Instead of WinForms, look into Unity or other game engines

Comment: or xaml perhaps. Look into the canvas object.

Comment: have you write this code or you copied from somewhere else ? .because if you write this code you can easily write further code...

Comment: You'll need to get the game physics right, regardless of what kind of class library you use.  Using xChange = -xChange is a pretty obvious bug, turns into a large negative value at the right end of the playground.  Learning how to debug small programs is the benefit of this kind of code, you do have to take the time.

Comment: _g xChange = -xChange is a pretty obvious bug_ Actually it is not as the variable only ever gets toggled.

Comment: Why would a Button click move the  ball? shouldn't it move a Paddle left/right?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a KeyDown event handler to your picDraw, then code what each key does (changing the ball position).

Here's an example from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeypress(v=vs.110).aspx

You migth need to look up ascii key codes for specific keys if i remember correctly.

In the future consider using Unity as at the moment you are not using the correct technology for what you are trying to achieve.